# Running out of system resources

Tags: java, list, resultset

I have a method that will take a `ResultSet` and create a `List` of `Object[]` for each row it reads. One of the queries that I put on the server gets over 4million rows back. However, each row (at max) is 40 characters.

Even though 4million rows is a poop ton, that plus with 40 chars per row shouldn't cause me to run out of resources, but alas it does.

```
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = someResultSet.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    someResultSet.last();
    int totalRows = someResultSet.getRow();
    List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList(totalRows);
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList();
    List<Object> addRow = new LinkedList();
    double someValue = 0d;
    for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(x+1));
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    someResultSet.beforeFirst();
    while (someResultSet.next()) {
        addRow.clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < columnNames.size(); x++) {
            if (someResultSet.getObject(x + 1) instanceof Double) {
                someValue = someResultSet.getDouble(x + 1);
                addRow.add(nf.format(someValue));
            }
            else if (someResultSet.getObject(x + 1) != null) addRow.add(someResultSet.getObject(x + 1).toString());
            else addRow.add("");
        }
        result.add(addRow.toArray());
    }
```

Why am I running out of system resources? On the box that I develop on, I have no issues running this, but on the box that this needs to run on I get no love.

Comment: 4M strings * 80 bytes/string = 320M.  You have to start with a 64 bit operating system.  The JVM and the rest of your code needs space, too.  You need to set Java options for generation sizes for sure.  Believe the JVM - if it says you have an out of memory error, then you do.

Comment: I have 8 gigs or ram on the box it will run on (a VM, btw)... this shouldn't be an issue, no?

Comment: 8G RAM on the box does not mean that you've given the JVM access to all ot it.  You should know how to configure memory on JDK 8: http://blog.sokolenko.me/2014/11/javavm-options-production.html